# $\lim_{n \to\infty} E(|S_n|)= \infty$ for $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ i.i.d. real RV with Var$(X_1)=1, E(X_1)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> **Problem:** For $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ i.i.d. real RV with Var$(X_1)=1$ and $E(X_1)=0$ and $S_n$ denoting the partial sum of the RVs we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E(|S_n|)=\infty $$

---

**My Approach:** I have managed to show, thanks to the **central limit theorem**, that $\exists p >0$ such that for large enough $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e. $n \geq n_0$) we have  \begin{align}P (|S_n| \geq \sqrt{n}) \geq p>0, \ \forall n \geq n_0 \tag{*} \end{align}

I do want to use * to conclude the statement. My idea was now to use that for a positive RV $X$ we have  $$E(X)= \int_0^\infty P(X \geq x) dx $$
However I am having trouble to connect this with my result (*) because evidently we have $P(|S_n| \geq \sqrt{n}) \geq P(|S_n| \geq n)$

I can write $$E(|S_n|) = \int_0^\infty P (|S_n| \geq x ) dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i P(|S_n| \geq x)dx \\ \geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i P(|S_n| \geq i) dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(|S_n| \geq i ) $$
I assume that I am on the wrong track. Maybe someone could provide me a hint to get me in the right direction again using (*) to conclude the statement in the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's where I went wrong. My problem is that I can't find a relation between $S_n$ and $X$. Indeed the CLT states that for large enough $n$ the RV $U_n:= S_n/ \sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ i.e. $\lim E(f(U_n))=E(f(N(0,1)))$ for all $f$ bounded.  The $|.|$ function is not bounded so I cannot use that here. However intuitively speaking (no rigor involved) the CLT would support/hint that for large enough $n $ we have $E(|S_n|/\sqrt{n})= E(|N(0,1)|)= \sqrt{2 / \pi } = (1/\sqrt{n})E(|S_n|)$, I could multiply by $\sqrt{n}$ here but nolonger take the limit.

Comment: That $E(|S_n|)\to\infty$ follows from the implication: $$P (|S_n| \geqslant \sqrt{n}) \geqslant p\implies E(|S_n|)\geqslant E(|S_n|\,;\;|S_n|\geqslant\sqrt{n})\geqslant\sqrt{n}\,P(|S_n|\geqslant\sqrt{n}){}{}{}{}{}\geqslant\sqrt{n}\,p$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this might be what @Did suggest in the comments. However, since I haven't dealt with conditional probability/expectation yet I will rewrite it in my own words.

Note that for all $a>0$ we have $a \mathbb{1}_{|X| \geq a} \leq |X|$. Applying this to the problem at hand we easily see that \begin{align}\mathbb{E} (|S_n|) \geq \mathbb{E}( \sqrt{n}  \cdot 1_{|S_n| \geq \sqrt{n}}) = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{E}(1_{|S_n| \geq\sqrt{n}}) = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{P}(|S_n| \geq \sqrt{n}) > \sqrt{n}p \end{align}
which concludes  the proof for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Not a whiff of conditional expectation in my comment, of course... You might want to note that $E(X;A)$ and $E(X\mid A)$ are not synonyms.